# How do I determine and subtract a percentage value from a dictionary?

Tags: python, math, percentage

Me and my friend are creating a stock market simulation for practice with python. I wanted generate a random number to calculate the percentage of each item in the dictionary, and subtract each items value by that percentage.

Here is the dictionary:

```
prices = {
    'SNAP': 84.55,
    'AAPL': 145.76,
    'TWTR': 62.25,
    'TSLA': 759.05,
    'NFLX': 587.55,
    'FB': 363.05,
    'MSFT': 299.50,
    'DIS': 182.87,
    'GPRO': 9.50,
    'SUBX': 113.41,
    'F': 13.49,
    'BABA': 160.00,
    'BAC': 40.40,
    'GE': 100.30,
    'GOOGL': 2811.00,
}
```

And here is what I have so far:

```
class major_events:
    def MarketCrash():
        market_loss = random.ranint(25, 50)
```

Not much progress with it yet but I guess that is why I am asking.

Comment: are you asking this: each value in prices divided by market loss * 100?

Comment: Instead of using a simple `dict`, you could try using `collections.Counter`, which is a subclass of `dict` specialised in dealing with positive counts. It only supports integers, but since all your prices have at most 2 decimal places, you could use cents as the unit.

Comment: @SujalSingh Pretty much, yeah.

Comment: @Stef Thanks. I will try that out.

Comment: Use a dictionary comprehension: `new_prices = {k: v * (1 - market_loss/100) for k, v in prices.items()}`

Comment: @tobias_k This would not work in my code. I would have to replace everything in my code with new_prices. It also would only have a 1 in 23 chance of actually working, as I use an if statement to see if the variable = 1 (determined by a randint), and if it is then it will run the market crash function.

Comment: @dubber Well, you can of course also re-assign to the old variable: `prices = {... for k, x in prices.items()}`. And you can add a condition to the dict comprehension if you want just some of the values to change: `{k: v if some_boolean else v * (...) for ....}`

Comment: @tobias_k When I run the program after I call the function, and look at the stock prices, all it shows is '{Ellipsis}'.

Comment: @dubber Looks like you have a self-reference in your dict, like `d = {1: 2}; d[3] = d`.

Comment: @tobias_k You mean something like this:                                                                                                                                 
 ```                                                                                                                                  def buy_stock(stock):
    global balance
    global SessionCost
    global TotalSpent
    global TotalBought
    if balance < prices[stock]:                                                                                          ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237419/discussion-between-dubber-and-tobias-k).